# m to the power of 0 in Church’s Numerals

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus, computation-theory, exponentiation, church-encoding

A topic on undergraduate level computer science.
I came upon a bothering problem about `(0 m)` in terms of exponentiation of church’s numerals in lambda calculus when reviewing the theory.
As far as I know, `(0 m)` when reduced results in `λx. x`, which is not `1 (= m^0)` as expected and even not within church’s numerals.

I adopt n of a natural number in lambda calculus encoded by church’s encodings usually as below

`n := λfx. (f^n x) = (f ... (f x))`

Many literatures say that

`EXP(m, n) := λmn. (n m)`

returns `m^n` for given `m` and `n` of church’s numerals, and I understand the function responds correctly in most cases.
But this is not the case when `n = 0` since

`(0 m) = ((λfx. x) m) → λx. x`

In mathematics, `1` is an identity element of natural numbers regarded as a multiplicative group, i.e. `x * 1 = 1 * x` for any `x` in `N`.  So if I set `EXP` function in the form of

`EXP’(m, n) := λmn. (n (MUL m) 1)`

for `MUL(m, n) = m * n`, this appears to work fine, coinciding the fact `m^0` is often defined as `1` in mathematics.  Also this seems straightforward in the sense of hyperoperation.

HYPEROPERATION: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation

I expect some criticisms like `m^0` is not necessarily `1` in math, and rigid mathematical guys would say it all depends on definitions.  But then is there any logical support for adopting the former style `EXP(m, n)`?  It doesn’t return church’s numerals when `n = 0`, so still seems poorly defined for me.

Question is

1. “Why the definition `EXP(m, n) := λmn. (n m)` is usually accepted for `m^n` even though
   its output can be non church’s numeral for church’s numeral inputs?”
2. “Do you know any slight correction of `EXP` so the function serves well for all church’s numeral inputs?”
3. “Any problem or misunderstanding on my criticism to `(0 m)`.”

In addition, are there logical backgrounds for the result of `(0 m)` to be `λx. x`, which is an identity element of function composition, instead of 1?  Is this just a coincidence or am I thinking this too seriously?

Any ideas are welcomed.

I want to follow wikipedia definitions of algebra related to church’s numerals if necessary.

CHURCH’S ENCODING: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding

Thanks.

Comment: This is a question that might be better suited for the computer science community on the stack exchange network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple misunderstanding: you say "`λx. x`, which is not `1`", but `λx. x` is indeed the Church numeral `1`. You probably know the Church numeral `1` as `λfx. f x`, but a simple eta-reduction and alpha-conversion show that this is equivalent to `λx. x`.

Comment: Aha!
You filled the missing piece.  Me idiot.
λfx. (f x) = λf. (λx. f x) →η λf. f →α λx. x